# Problem in gaining uid of the system caller in a system call LKM using cred.h

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, c, uid

I was trying to get the `uid` of the process runner which is calling my syscall. I use `linux/cred.h` and its macro called `current_uid()` .

The problem is that it returns a type which is unknown for me, `kuid_t`. So I can't save the return value to an `int` type static variable. Here are parts of the code and error:

```
static int getuid(void){
    return current_uid();
}

static int caller_uid = getuid();
```

error:

```
error: incompatible types when returning type ‘kuid_t’ {aka ‘const struct <anonymous>’} but ‘int’ was expected
  current_cred()->xxx;   \
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kuid_t` is defined in `linux/uidgid.h` it's just a simple struct with one `uid_t` member.

```
typedef struct {
    uid_t val;
} kuid_t;
```

You should be able to get the `uid_t` value using `current_uid().val` and `uid_t` is just an `usigned int`.